# Merge ActiveRecord Model objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a simple way to do this.
Let's say i have 4 `Person` objects that somehow refer to the same person.
All of them have some attributes correctly filled, e.g. `@person1` has `age` and `gender`, `@person2` have `last_name`, `@person3` have `observation` and `@person4` have `mother_name`.

In addition to these simple attributes, there is some relashionships between another `ActiveRecord` models.
For example `@person1` might have 2 notes, `@person2` might have 1 note and 2 adresses, and so on.

The thing i am looking for is a way to make all these four objects to be merged together preserving all the filled attributes and all the relashionships.
Example, in the end i would have something like this: a `Person` object with `age, gender, last_name, observation, mother_name, 3 notes, 2 adresses, etc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at the ar_merge gem yet? https://github.com/grosser/ar_merge
It hasn't been updated for a couple of months but looking at it, I guess it should still be compatible.